# Is there a way to make Python Requests take a HTTP 302 redirect and include cookies received in the initial response?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm trying to script a request to a server using Python's `requests` module. One of the requests returns a HTTP 302 redirect along with a cookie. This cookie is then used in accessing the redirection target URL. However, `requests` doesn't seem to forward this cookie to the new URL when it takes the redirect.

The obvious workaround is to set`allow_redirects=False` in the initial request, extract the cookies from the response, and then take the redirect myself by sending another request after setting the appropriate cookie values (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391272/python-requests-how-to-get-response-cookie-from-302-redirect)). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do all the requests in a `with requests.Session() as session:` block and use for example `session.get(...)`.

Comment: @KlausD. This is interesting; I didn't even realize `requests.Session` defines a `close` method. That's the only thing its `__exit__` method calls, and `Session.close` doesn't appear to be mentioned anywhere in [the doc](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects). The context manager usage is shown, but only once.